# date-picker global definition for firstDayOfWeek from Element-Ui possible?

Tags: datepicker, global, definition, element-ui

I'm using the component DatePicker from Element-Ui.

The firstDayOfWeek, which is shown in the calender is set to Sunday by default. I want to set it to Monday, like so:

```
<el-date-picker
    type="date"
    format="dd.MM.yyyy"
    value-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
    v-model="expireDate"
    :picker-options="pickerOptions"
/>
```

In my data object I have:

```
data() {
  return {
     expireDate : ''
     pickerOptions: {
     firstDayOfWeek: 1
     }
   }
}
```

But I want to define the firstDayOfWeek globally, because I have many datePickers in my Code. Ist this possible?

I already tried this, but it's not working:

```
Vue.use(ElementUI);
const pickerOptions = {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1
}
Vue.use(DatePicker, pickerOptions);
```

Comment: you can use mixins for that https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html